# Symfony 2, validate standard authentication

Tags: symfony

I've built authentication, based on tutorial.

How can I validate that form? I have no controller action for that. Only route login_check. All the operations performed by Symfony.

Here is  [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

Authentication, using traditional login form only requires from developer to create entity (User) and one action of controller that displays login form.

There is no need to create action for route, that handles form data. Symfony does it automatically using events listners. So I don't know, where do I need to write something like that:

```
$errors = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($user);
```

where user is object created from entity User.  Or validate POST data.

p.s.
sorry for my english.

Comment: Or at least show us the tutorial and the step you are stuck with

Comment: Why not use [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)?